# How do I quickly migrate my flutter project to null safety?

Tags: flutter, dart, null, nullable

My question is not about how to upgrade my Flutter or Dart versions...

I've tried to avoid null safety for the longest time, because I don't see the problem with the concept of "null", my app works perfectly fine. But now with the newest flutter version, you HAVE to use null safety, you have no choice.

So I did some research on how to migrate, turns out the "migrate" command isn't available in the newest dart version, so I had to do "flutter downgrade" (will upgrade again once I'm done), and after that I'll do "dart migrate".

My problem is, when I attempt to run "dart migrate", I get 205 analysis issues (please let me know if it would be helpful to provide more detail, maybe paste the output here).

Do I now have to manually add question marks and exclamation marks to each of those 205 areas in my code? And this is only one of my projects... I still got another, bigger one, which I have to migrate as well. Is there any way to automate this?

---

Edit: I added a screenshot of part of the output I get when trying to run "dart migrate"

[image]

Comment: "I don't see the problem with the concept of "null", my app works perfectly fine".  Null-safety isn't against the concept of null, it's about ensuring that you know exactly when references might be `null` and don't get surprised.  It's about transforming potential runtime failures into compile-time ones.  Null-safety is just an extended form of type-safety.

Comment: You need to rewrite the problematic code. I mostly write in Delphi, and I also didn't see the point in null-safaty at first, but then I changed my mind. This is a very cool thing